# How to list saved networks in Android 10?

Tags: android, android-wifi

On Android Oreo or lower, [WifiManager#getConfiguredNetworks()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getConfiguredNetworks()) method was available to list saved network.

I tested this out in Android 10 emulator and it returns a blank list (as mentioned in the docs). Does anyone know whats the alternate?

**Official docs**

> This method was deprecated in API level 29. a) See
>   WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder#build() for new mechanism to trigger
>   connection to a Wi-Fi network. b) See
>   addNetworkSuggestions(java.util.List),
>   removeNetworkSuggestions(java.util.List) for new API to add Wi-Fi
>   networks for consideration when auto-connecting to wifi. Compatibility
>   Note: For applications targeting Build.VERSION_CODES.Q or above, this
>   API will return an empty list, except for:

Comment: any solution for this?

Comment: Haven't found one yet